# Custom Post Type Template Hierarchy - Single post template

Tags: custom-post-types, template-hierarchy

I have registered a custom post type and I am trying to make posts of that type display in a specific template file but can't figure out what to name my template file in order for the posts to use it.

Here's my code in my functions file:

```
function digital_post_type() {

  register_post_type( 'digital',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Digital Assets' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Digital Asset' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Digital'),
        'name_admin_bar' => __( 'Digital Assets'),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New'),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Digital Asset'),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Digital Asset'),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Digital Asset'),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Digital Asset'),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Digital Assets')
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'digital_assets' ),
      'supports' => array( 'title','thumbnail', 'excerpt' )
    )
  );

}

add_action( 'init', 'digital_post_type' );
```

I tried naming my template file `single-digital_assets.php` but the posts are still using the default `single.php` template. I also tried resaving my permalink settings to make sure it wasn't a caching issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post type name is `digital` (`register_post_type( 'digital',`) so the template should be `single-digital.php`.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I thought it was the slug. Working great now!